# forkJoin Http requests not working as should

Tags: angular, http

I worked in the past with forkJoin and all was good. I have this code.

```
 getData() {
    const me = this.http.get<any>(`${API_URL}/api/users/me`);
    forkJoin([
        me
    ])
        .subscribe(
            response => {console.log("RES: ", response)},
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('ssssss')
        )
}
```

I can see the request being made in network, but no console log outputs. What am i doing wrong ?

"rxjs": "^6.6.3"

"@angular/common": "^10.0.14"

Comment: **1.** Why use `forkJoin` for a single request? **2.** What is type of expected response? Is it a JSON object or plain text or something else?

Comment: Why are you using `forkJoin` since you have only one observable ? What if you try with just `me.subscribe(console.log)` ?

Comment: I plan to add more requests there.  And the response is JSON.

Comment: Can you put it on stackblitz?

Comment: Show a screenshot of the response from the network tab.

Comment: It might be because forkJoin only handles completed observables. To fix this, add a `.pipe(first())` to your `me`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the responses in an array as well. Please see my example below:

```
const me1 = this.http.get<any>(`${API_URL}/api/users/me1`);
const me2 = this.http.get<any>(`${API_URL}/api/users/me2`);

forkJoin([
          me1,
          me2
      ]).subscribe(
          ([res1, res2]) => {
              console.log(res1);
              console.log(res2);
          }
          );
```